# How To Write A Query With A CTE And A Left Join

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, common-table-expression

I am trying to have a calendar table with my CTE and set it up so that my dates in my query display like this

> Jan 18
> Jan 19
> Feb 18
> Feb 19

Now this is my DDL and this is the query I attempted, but in MySql Workbench I'm getting the error that there is an error in my sql somewhere.

This is the exact error:

> Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RECURSIVE cte_months_to_pull AS ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@start_date, '%Y-%m-01'' at line 1

Can someone assist?

If it's easier this is a SQL Fiddle of everything http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/300f9d/1

```
CREATE TABLE PrevYear (


`EmployeeNumber` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `SaleAmount` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `SaleDate` date NOT NULL,
  `EmployeeName` char(17) NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE CurrentYear (
  `EmployeeNumber` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `SaleAmount` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `SaleDate` date NOT NULL,
  `EmployeeName` char(17) NOT NULL
); 

INSERT INTO CurrentYear
VALUES ('ea12', '100', '2019-01-10', 'Maggie Samuels');
INSERT INTO CurrentYear
VALUES ('ea12', '199', '2019-01-13', 'Sam Stoner');
INSERT INTO CurrentYear
VALUES ('ea12', '100', '2019-03-01', 'Jake Jolel');
INSERT INTO CurrentYear
VALUES ('ls22', '100', '2019-05-01', 'Maggie Samuels');

INSERT INTO PrevYear
VALUES ('ea12', '100', '2018-01-10', 'Maggie Samuels');
INSERT INTO PrevYear
VALUES ('ea12', '199', '2018-01-13', 'Sam Stoner');
INSERT INTO PrevYear
VALUES ('ea12', '100', '2018-03-01', 'Sam Stoner');
INSERT INTO PrevYear
VALUES ('ls22', '100', '2018-05-01', 'Maggie Samuels');
```

And this is the query I try:

```
    SET @start_date = '20190102';
SET @number_of_months = 12;
WITH RECURSIVE
cte_months_to_pull AS (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@start_date, '%Y-%m-01')
         - INTERVAL @number_of_months MONTH AS month_to_pull
    UNION ALL
    SELECT month_to_pull + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    FROM cte_months_to_pull
    WHERE month_to_pull < @start_date + INTERVAL @number_of_months - 2 MONTH
)
SELECT Date_format(saledate, '%m-%Y') AS Month,
               employeename,
               Sum(saleamount)                AS IA
        FROM   currentyear
        WHERE  employeename = 'Maggie Samuels'
        GROUP  BY Date_format(saledate, '%m-%Y'), employeename
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Date_format(saledate, '%m-%Y') AS Month,
               employeename,
               Sum(saleamount)                AS IA
        FROM   prevyear
        WHERE  employeename = 'Maggie Samuels'
        GROUP  BY Date_format(saledate, '%m-%Y'), employeename
LEFT JOIN cte_months_to_pull (
    Select DATE_Format(month_to_pull, '%b %y')
    FROM cte_months_to_pull
) AS YRS ON month_to_pull = saledate
ORDER BY MONTH(month_to_pull), YEAR(month_to_pull)
```

Comment: . . What is your question?

Comment: If you run the fiddle - you'll get the error `DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL; only SELECT statements are allowed. Put DDL and DML in the schema panel.` - What's wrong with my syntax?

Comment: . . Try using db<>fiddle.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - here is db<>fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pam3M2129XyWNRoUQerMMW/0

Comment: CTE requires MySQL 8.0. You're using 5.x in both fiddles.

Comment: After changing the MySQL version in the fiddle, it gets a different error: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ciMZbsVD2Zugh2imtKxZ3S/1 This error is because you have the `LEFT JOIN` in the wrong place.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. You can't put `LEFT JOIN` at the end of a `SELECT` statement. It goes after the `FROM` clause. And what is the `(select ...)` after `LEFT JOIN cte_months_to_pull` supposed to mean?

Comment: @Barmar - I am wanting to capture the `Sum(saleamount)` for each month in 2018 and 2019 for a specifed salesperson.  But have the data display in the format of Jan 18 Jan 19 etc which is why I'm trying the order by clause.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Chop out code until there is no syntax error then add back. This is clearly not "minimal" code for your error. [mre] Read the manual re syntax & restrictions on semantics & look at examples & if you are adding syntax that is new to you add it to some much simpler query that you know works. First learn the syntax & solve that error, ask about your goal later when you get stuck adding some part that doesn't work to code that you know works. Is your post incorporating all the comments at this point? Please delete or flag for deletion comments not needed.

Comment: The syntax for union is (with-)select union (with-)select. Your code violates that. Read the grammar & manual sections--for select, with & union. When debugging build your expression tree from smaller parts that work to combinations that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you are using MySQL version older than 8.0 which doesn't support RECURSIVE CTEs. I have tried your query with some minor updates on 8.0 and it worked fine -

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte_months_to_pull AS (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@start_date, '%Y-%m-01')
         - INTERVAL @number_of_months MONTH AS month_to_pull
    UNION ALL
    SELECT month_to_pull + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    FROM cte_months_to_pull
    WHERE month_to_pull < @start_date + INTERVAL @number_of_months - 2 MONTH
)
SELECT YRS.months_to_pull
      ,T.employeename
      ,COALESCE(T.IA, 0) IA
FROM (SELECT DATE_Format(month_to_pull, '%b-%Y') months_to_pull
      FROM cte_months_to_pull
      ORDER BY months_to_pull
     ) AS YRS
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Date_format(saledate, '%b-%Y') AS `Month`
                 ,employeename
                 ,Sum(saleamount) AS IA
           FROM   CurrentYear
           WHERE  employeename = 'Maggie Samuels'
           GROUP  BY Date_format(saledate, '%b-%Y'), employeename
           UNION ALL
           SELECT Date_format(saledate, '%b-%Y')
                 ,employeename
                 ,Sum(saleamount)
           FROM   PrevYear
           WHERE  employeename = 'Maggie Samuels'
           GROUP  BY Date_format(saledate, '%b-%Y'), employeename) T
ON YRS.months_to_pull = T.`Month`
ORDER BY month(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-',months_to_pull), '%d-%b-%Y'))
        ,YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-',months_to_pull), '%d-%b-%Y'))
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=de8f0b47476fcc14d0670cf65079c3cf)

Since there is no expected output, I have only tried till running the query.

Comment: Hi - thank you for your help!  I appreciate your help with making this a valid MySql query.  I need the result set to return in this format Jan 2018 Jan 2019, Feb 2018 Feb 2019 etc.  It seems the Order By is being ignored now?  If there is no data for the employee for that month I want it to show 0.  But every month needs to be returned.